# How to add features from earlier stages of Neural Network to latter stages of Neural Network?

Tags: python, dotnetnuke, tf.keras

I have the following situation

```
class SomeClass():
    def foo(self, X, y):
        self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(640, 480, 3))
        self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)) # 1
        self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu')
        self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2)) # 2
```

Now I would like to add 1 and 2 and to pass this to next layer in my DNN. I have tried everything, but every time I get problem with KerasTensor & Layer class. It says it needs to be subclass of Layer, when I do that I still get the same error.

I have tried everything.

Comment: I think you need to remove the DotNetNuke tag and add something else. Maybe there is a proper tag for your flavor of Neural Networks (DNN)?